# I get a "failed to store the wallet" message after trying to update to monero-gui-v0.17.1.9

Tags: linux, wallet-recovery, ubuntu, update

I am using monero-gui-v0.17.1.6 and was advised to update. When I try to use it,it takes me to the Restore menu.
I enter all the correct details but when I enter "next" I get
a flash telling me "failed to store wallet". My O.S. is Zorin
15.3 on a desktop P.C.

Comment: Can you try opening your wallet simply through the `Open a wallet from file` option?

Comment: That is what I tried but perhaps I did it wrong, monero-gui-v017.1.9 created a new directory and I think I pointed it to the monero-wallet-gui.AppImage.

Comment: You should be able to select the 'old' `.keys` file simply. Would you mind re-checking?